# SQL Select Statement off by one variable but can't find issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I am testing out how to use a count-variable to have a column in my SELECT output be dedicated to simply listing the row number. So if I had 3 rows outputed in the query, then they would be numbered {1,2,3} in their "rank" column as I have written....

Furthermore, I am wanting to select only one row, where that row's "rank" column is 1. The following SQL statement works (making sure I SET @rownum=0 everytime) however, it doesn't give me the appropriate output. So looking for rank=1 I get the row where rank is actually 2. If I look for rank=2 then I get where its really 3. and so on. If I then search for rank=0, I DO NOT get where the rank is 1 Surprisingly. So I'm lost

```
  SET @rownum=0;

  SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank,
        r.id, c.fname, r.pickupCity, r.pickupState 

    FROM request r  
    INNER JOIN client c  ON r.client = c.id 
    INNER JOIN pickup p ON r.id = p.request
    INNER JOIN driver d ON d.id = p.driver

    WHERE date = '2018-04-18' AND d.id = 1
    HAVING rank = 1;
```

[image]

Comment: `HAVING` without `GROUP BY` is invalid.  It doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @Eric the reason why I use HAVING is because I really want to say "WHERE rank = 1" but this doesn't work because Where cannot refer to aliases such as rank

Comment: Can't you put `@rownum + 1 = 1` in the `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a really important point:  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You should expect no correspondence between ids and row numbers without an `order by`.  Period.  And this is even more notable in queries that use joins.

I would suggest using an `order by` in a subquery, like this:

```
SELECT x.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
FROM (SELECT r.id, c.fname, r.pickupCity, r.pickupState 
      FROM request r JOIN 
           client c
           ON r.client = c.id 
           pickup p
           ON r.id = p.request
           driver d
           ON d.id = p.driver
      WHERE date = '2018-04-18' AND d.id = 1
      ORDER BY r.id
     ) x CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rownum := 0) params
HAVING rank = 1;
```

That said, another way to write the query would use `limit` and `offset`:

```
      SELECT r.id, c.fname, r.pickupCity, r.pickupState 
      FROM request r JOIN 
           client c
           ON r.client = c.id 
           pickup p
           ON r.id = p.request
           driver d
           ON d.id = p.driver
      WHERE date = '2018-04-18' AND d.id = 1
      ORDER BY r.id
      LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0;
```

You can change the `OFFSET` value to get rows other than the first.